# In MVC: Copy view elements by jQuery and retrive value of them at relevant controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my view:

```
@model PhoneBook.Models.Number
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.AddNewNumber.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contact.Id)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Number</legend>
    <div class="TargetElements">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberKind)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberKind.Title, NumberKinds)
        </div>
    </div>
<p>
        <input class="AddNew" value="Add New" type="button" /></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

I need when press the "Add New" button All the elements in `<div class="TargetElements">` Copied and in when press the submit button I can achieve all values.

At now i use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.AddNew').click(function () {
    $(".TargetElements:first").clone().insertAfter('.TargetElements');
});
});
```

but there is 2 problem with this:
1- when I add first time one div(include target elements) added but in second time two div added and grow in ascending
2- when copy the elements all the value of target element added but I need Empty inputs to add new value

How Can I fix the Script?

And finally I don't know how can I retrieve values of all element in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Number NewNumber, FormCollection collection) {
}
```

Comment: Pressing AddNew wil copy elements or elements values and where?
I think you are looking for ajax form, and instead of using FormCollection use the a ViewModel.
Maybe Your solution is this: http://www.frederikvig.com/2010/05/creating-a-contact-form-with-asp-net-mvc/
You should only hook the copy part, but that is done with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1- when I add first time one div(include target elements) added but
>   in second time two div added and grow in ascending.**

You insert the new field after every field that exist, take a look at:
$(".TargetElements:first").clone().**insertAfter('.TargetElements');**

Should be:
$(".TargetElements:first").clone().**insertAfter('.TargetElements:last');**

> **2- when copy the elements all the value of target element added but I need Empty inputs to add new value**

There is no one that stops you from clearing the values with Javascript, just go through all the input elements in the new clone and clear their values.

```
function cloneTargetBox() {
    var targetBoxClone = $(".target-elements:first").clone();
    targetBoxClone.find("input").val(""); //Not sure this is the proper way, but hey, it works
    targetBoxClone.insertAfter(".target-elements:last")
}
```

Here is a code sample of what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/KVqW8/3/

Comment: Wobin Anderson :  Thank you Robin, that solve all thing but how can I retrieve the values, I ask it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164257/mvc-retrive-multi-entry-from-view-in-controller

Comment: Hello @Robin Can you suggest how can I post the data from the cloned row to the Controller.