# MVC Retrieve Multi Entry from View in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
            Number newNumber = new Number();
        return View(newNumber);
    }
```

and View :

```
@model PhoneBook.Models.Number
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.AddNewNumber.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contact.Id)
<fieldset>
<legend>Number</legend>
<div class="TargetElements">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberKind)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberKind.Title, NumberKinds)
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <input class="AddNew" value="Add New" type="button" /></p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
```

By press AddNew button (use jQuery AddNewNumber.js) new input+DropDown Added to form in client side. But there is a problem in retrieve values, When I have one entry element(include input+DropDown) I can retrieve values like the following in post of my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Number NewNumber, FormCollection collection) {
            db.Numbers.Add(NewNumber);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

But when there is multi-entry how can I retrieve values and add them to DataBase?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MVC: Copy view elements by jQuery and retrive value of them at relevant controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163796/in-mvc-copy-view-elements-by-jquery-and-retrive-value-of-them-at-relevant-contr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use by the name of element like this:

```
string[] PhoneNumbers = collection.GetValues("PhoneNumber");
```

Answer (score 1):

You want all of your input elements to have the same name.  Then in your POST action method, the parameter would be List.  Here is an example:
[Model Binding to a List of objects](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx#s8-binding-with-a-list-of-class-types)